# MySQL Workbench 6.3.9 fails to connect to anything on Windows

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using a Windows 10 Machine with MySQL Workbench 6.3.9.  When I try to connect to my previously set up connections all I get is an error saying it can't connect.  The message is "SSL connection error: unknown error number"

When I run the same version of MySQL Workbench on macOS it connects just fine.

Can anyone help me out here?  I have no idea what is wrong here.

Comment: seems to be trying to connect through SSL instead on the standard port 3306. Can you verify the connection parameters?

Comment: I should probably add that my connections are going through an SSH tunnel.  So the connection Method is Standard TCP/IP over SSH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for my case.  It turns out that the DB admins recently updated some SSL protocols which isn't compatible with Workbench.  Disabling the use of SSL makes the connection successful, albeit not as secure.

Comment: Thanks for posting your findings that might be helpful to others.

Comment: No problem. :-)